# What is the MultiSendCallOnly address on Avalanche?

Tags: gnosis-safe

On the changelogs it says the `MultiSendCallOnly` contract is at `0x40A2aCCbd92BCA938b02010E17A5b8929b49130D` on Ethereum. Is this contract deployed on Avalanche? And what is the address?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.3.0/multi_send_call_only.json

It is deployed at https://snowtrace.io/address/0xA1dabEF33b3B82c7814B6D82A79e50F4AC44102B#code